# HaProxy has the Loadbalancer for spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, haproxy

i have configured haproxy as the load balancer for two containerised spring boot application

Below is the sample docker compose file configuration

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  wechat-1:
    image: xxxxxx/wechat-social-connector:2.0.0
    container_name: wechat-1
    ports:
     - 81:8000
    networks:
     - web 
    #depends_on:
     #- wechat-2

  wechat-2:
    image: xxxxxxxxx/wechat-social-connector:2.0.0
    container_name: wechat-2
    ports:
     - 82:8000
    networks:
     - web

  haproxy:
    build: ./haproxy
    container_name: haproxy
    ports:
     - 80:80
    networks:
     - web
    #depends_on:
     #- wechat-1


networks:
 web:
```

Docker file

```
FROM haproxy:2.1.4
COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

HA Configuration file

```
global
    debug
    daemon
    maxconn 2000

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client  50000ms
    timeout server  50000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    default_backend servers

backend servers
    mode http
    option httpchk
    balance roundrobin
    server wechat-1 wechat-1:81 check
    server wechat-2 wechat-2:82 check
```

when i am trying to access my endpoints using the port number 80 i always getting the service unavailable.

After debugging from the haproxy logs noticed the below error

```
Creating haproxy  ... done
Creating wechat-2 ... done
Creating wechat-1 ... done
Attaching to wechat-2, wechat-1, haproxy
haproxy     | Available polling systems :
haproxy     |       epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
haproxy     |        poll : pref=200,  test result OK
haproxy     |      select : pref=150,  test result FAILED
haproxy     | Total: 3 (2 usable), will use epoll.
haproxy     | 
haproxy     | Available filters :
haproxy     |   [SPOE] spoe
haproxy     |   [CACHE] cache
haproxy     |   [FCGI] fcgi-app
haproxy     |   [TRACE] trace
haproxy     |   [COMP] compression
haproxy     | Using epoll() as the polling mechanism.
haproxy     | [NOTICE] 144/185524 (1) : New worker #1 (8) forked
haproxy     | [WARNING] 144/185524 (8) : Server servers/wechat-1 is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
haproxy     | [WARNING] 144/185525 (8) : Server servers/wechat-2 is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
haproxy     | [ALERT] 144/185525 (8) : backend 'servers' has no server available!
```

from the logs i understand when haproxy is not able to connect the other two containers which are running perfectly with out any issues.
i tired to use the depends_on attribute(commented for time being) still the issue same .

Can some one help me in fixing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below configuration. Few changes in the `haproxy.cfg`

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  wechat-1:
    image: nginx
    container_name: wechat-1
    ports:
     - 81:80
    networks:
     - web
    depends_on:
     - wechat-2

  wechat-2:
    image: nginx
    container_name: wechat-2
    ports:
     - 82:80
    networks:
     - web

  haproxy:
    build: ./haproxy
    container_name: haproxy
    ports:
     - 80:80
    networks:
     - web
    depends_on:
     - wechat-1

networks:
 web:
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM haproxy
COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

`haproxy.cfg`

```
global
    debug
    daemon
    maxconn 2000

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client  50000ms
    timeout server  50000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    default_backend servers

backend servers
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    balance roundrobin
    server wechat-1 wechat-1:80 check
    server wechat-2 wechat-2:80 check
```

Logs of HAPROXY

```
Attaching to wechat-2, wechat-1, haproxy
haproxy     | Using epoll() as the polling mechanism.
haproxy     | Available polling systems :
haproxy     |       epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
haproxy     |        poll : pref=200,  test result OK
haproxy     |      select : pref=150,  test result FAILED
haproxy     | Total: 3 (2 usable), will use epoll.
haproxy     | 
haproxy     | Available filters :
haproxy     |   [SPOE] spoe
haproxy     |   [CACHE] cache
haproxy     |   [FCGI] fcgi-app
haproxy     |   [TRACE] trace
haproxy     |   [COMP] compression
haproxy     | [NOTICE] 144/204217 (1) : New worker #1 (6) forked
```

Comment: Its working now . Do i have supposed to use the internal port instead of external port ? what reason can you explain me

Comment: That’s how HAProxy works - service Name:containerPort . As external port is for you to directly access the service but behind the proxy, requests goes om the same port

Comment: If you want to take a look at a tutorial, please have a look here
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/haproxy-l7-load-balancing-with-docker-containers/